# What effect does Realm choice have and is it permanent?

Tags: rage-of-bahamut

I picked up *Rage of Bahamut*, a mobile CCG game (Android version). The first step of the Tutorial asks me to choose a realm, either Man, Gods or Demons. I'm not quite sure what, if any, effect this has on actual gameplay though.

It also marks the Gods realm as "Recommended", and it says that if I pick the Gods realm, I will get more friend requests. I am unsure as to how the realm choice affects my potential friend availability.

Is this purely a cosmetic choice, or does this actually have an effect on my gameplay and the cards I can use? The description for all three realms starts out saying "Harness the power of..." and then goes on to list different characters for the realm types, like Lancelot for Man, Odin for Gods, and Bahamut for Demons, so this leads me to believe that this will limit what cards I can play with. Is this true?

Can I change my realm after I have chosen it, or am I locked into a specific realm permanently once I make my decision?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have chosen a Realm, you cannot change your choice.  The actual effect is rather minimal, you get a small boost (both Atk and Def I believe) during battles with other players for cards that match your Realm.  Your Realm does not change what cards you have access to, or what cards you can use, just adds the small bonus in battle.  Really, your Realm choice does not really matter.

Answer (score -1):

As above but also in general:

- Man: Better defense, 2 legend cards
- Demon: Better attack, 1 legend card
- Gods: More all-rounded, 1 legend card